# How to get except between two Dictionaries<int, IEnumerable<string>>?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two Dictionaries>

```
var test1 = await GetTest1();
var test2 = await GetTest2();
var groupedTest1 = test1.GroupBy(j => j.someField1)
                        .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, d => d.Select(s => s.someField2));
var groupedTest2 = test2.GroupBy(a => a.someField1)
                       .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, d => d.Select(s => s.someField2));
```

And I need two get the difference between them.
For example:

```
var result = groupedTest1.Except(groupedTest2);
```

If groupedTest1 contains something IEnumerable which contains in groupedTest2 I don't need to include this. Besides, I need to include check only for a similar key. My question is:
How can I do it?

> groupedTest1 : {    {    Key: 1,    IEnumerable: "test1, test2"    }, 
>   {    Key: 2,    IEnumerable: "test3, test4"    } }  groupedTest2 : {
>   {    Key: 2,    IEnumerable: "test3, test4"    } }
>
> result should be     Key: 1,    IEnumerable: "test1, test2"

Comment: Does the order matter? Is "test3, test4" considered the same as "test4, test3" (assuming that each testN is an individual string in the enumerable)?

Comment: @John order doesn`t matter

Comment: Does the key matter in this? So, in your example groupTest2 starts with Key2, but if that was Key1, would the result be the same or would that result in groupTest2 now be seen as something different as it has a different key?

Comment: Did you try anything? What's the actual problem?

Comment: @sr28, yes - key the matters

Comment: What if one has `Key 1: "test1, test2"`, and the other has `Key 2: "test1, test2, test3"`

Comment: @John nothing, If Key1: "test1, test" and other Key 1: "test1, test2, test3" then display only Key1 "test3"

Comment: That's not nothing.

Comment: Ok, so to be clear Key matters and based of the Key you then care about items that don't match in the IEnumerable.

Comment: Please update your question with one full proper requirement so we don't have to gather them in bits and pieces from the comments section

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it you effectively have 2 actions; first, get all the keys that don't match and their entire entry should be in the result, and second for matching keys only get the values that don't match. I've put together a little console app to display this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //2 test dictionaries. Key 1 and it's values should be displayed and Key 3 with only "test5".
        var test1 = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            { 1, new List<string>{ "test1", "test2" } },
            { 2, new List<string>{ "test3", "test4" } },
            { 3, new List<string>{ "test3", "test4", "test5" } }
        };

        var test2 = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            { 2, new List<string>{ "test3", "test4" } },
            { 3, new List<string>{ "test3", "test4" } }
        };

        //get non-matching keys first.
        Console.WriteLine("Non-matching keys:");
        var entriesWithNoMatch = test1.Where(x => !test2.ContainsKey(x.Key));
        foreach (var entry in entriesWithNoMatch)
        {
            WriteResults(entry.Key, entry.Value.ToList());
        }

        //get matching keys and compare values
        Console.WriteLine("Matching keys, non-matching values:");
        var matchingKeys = test1.Keys.Intersect(test2.Keys);
        foreach (var match in matchingKeys)
        {
            var result = new KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<string>>(match, test1[match].Except(test2[match]));
            if (result.Value.Count() > 0)
            {
                WriteResults(match, result.Value.ToList());
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //simple method to loop through results displaying key and results.
    static void WriteResults(int key, IList<string> results)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var r in results)
        {
            sb.Append(r + ",");
        }

        if (sb.Length > 1)
        {
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Key: " + key.ToString() + ", results: " + sb.ToString());

        sb.Clear();
    }
```

Results:

[image]